# How to make Orbit Controls auto rotate on different axis?

Tags: javascript, three.js

How do I make the Orbit Controls auto rotate on different axis than the default one?

`controls = new OrbitControls(this.camera, this.renderer.domElement);
controls.rotateSpeed = 0.4;
controls.autoRotate = true;
controls.autoRotateSpeed = 10;`

So what do I need to add to this code ?

Comment: `OrbitControls` can only auto rotate around the Y-axis. You would have to change the implementation of `OrbitControls` if you want a different behavior.

Comment: @FilipFrank The axis on which `OrbitControls` rotates is the same axis as the camera up direction: `camera.up.set( 0, 0, 1 );`